# Optimization of code / implementing "for" loop instead of long "if - else if - else"

Tags: c++, for-loop, qt4

To say in brief about my QT GUI C++ program,

I have 4 labels, `label1`, `label2`, `label3`, `label4` and a `spinBox`, `comboBox` and `pushButton`.

The functional (user operation logic) example,

```
if spinBox value = 1, on pushButton click, current comboBox index (text) = my_stringarray[0]
if spinBox value = 2, on pushButton click, current comboBox index (text) = my_stringarray[1]
if spinBox value = 3, on pushButton click, current comboBox index (text) = my_stringarray[2]
if spinBox value = 4, on pushButton click, current comboBox index (text) = my_stringarray[3]
```

now, the `spinBox` is bound 1-4 (i.e. in reference to the four qlabels `label1 to 4`) and the `comboBox` indices are "RED", "GREEN", "BLUE", "YELLOW"

the desired output logic is->

```
if my_stringarray[0] is RED set label1 color RED
if my_stringarray[0] is GREEN set label1 color GREEN
if my_stringarray[0] is BLUE set label1 color BLUE
if my_stringarray[0] is YELLOW set label1 color YELLOW
.
.
. and so on.
```

The same is also implemented by me by a rather long chain of `if - else if - else` commands which is getting the job done but seems not okay. So I am looking to implement a for loop solution for it, but cant make out how to initialize the loop parameters properly.

Any help / guideline with my rookie problem with the loop parameter initializing is highly appreciated.

```
Original code with "if - else if - else"

//for label1 color

if(settingsdialog->m_mystringarray[0]=="RED"
{
    ui->label1->setStyleSheet("QLabel{background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0)}");
    ui->label1->setText("I AM RED");
    qDebug()<<"label1 set RED";
}

else if(settingsdialog->m_mystringarray[0]=="GREEN"
{
    ui->label1->setStyleSheet("QLabel{background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0)}");
    ui->label1->setText("I AM GREEN");
    qDebug()<<"label1 set GREEN";
}

else if(settingsdialog->m_mystringarray[0]=="BLUE"
{
    ui->label1->setStyleSheet("QLabel{background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255)}");
    ui->label1->setText("I AM BLUE");
    qDebug()<<"label1 set BLUE";
}
```

and so on and on and on... as setting texts also involved, I think only a `for` loop can be my salvation...

Comment: Why don't you use [Qt5](http://qt-project.org/qt5)? Qt4 is quite old, and Qt5 brings many significant improvements!

Comment: since the entirety of my work is made on qt4 so it will be a while to shift everything to qt5.. plus i am still learning so i guess qt4 has all the functionalities qt5 has to offer more or less.. but thanx, i ll surely keep it in mind..

Comment: No, Qt5 is C++11 compatible. This is a huge win.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an [std::map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) associating strings to numbers:

```
static std::map<std::string,int> mapcolors;
```

You'll initialize it e.g. with

```
mapcolors["RED"]= RedColor;
mapcolors["BLUE"] = BlueColor;
```

I would suggest to **code in [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) and upgrade to [Qt5](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt5-intro.html)** (notably because C++11 is a *huge win* w.r.t. older versions of C++). You might even have the color be some [enum class](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum) (then change the declaration of `mapcolors` accordingly)

BTW, you actual performance issue is perhaps the use at runtime of `ui->label1->setStyleSheet("QLabel{background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0)}");` since the `setStyleSheet` has to "interpret" the `"QLabel{background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0)}"` string. It is probably not in a sequence of a dozen of `if` comparing strings (or perhaps even two hundreds of them!). Perhaps you should use some `std::map<std::string,QStyle*> mapstyles` instead, then

```
auto it = mapstyles.find(settingsdialog->m_mystringarray[0]);
if (it != mapstyles.end())
   ui->label1->setStyle(it->second);
```

You could even better associate both style and label text and have some `std::map<std::string,std::pair<Style*,std::string>> maplook;` etc... The second element of the pair being the string label (which might be some  `QString` instead of `std::string`)

<sup>With some efforts you could adapt this solution to the older Qt4 using C++98, but your code would be longer and less readable.</sup>

Comment: indeed it is.. in my actual program there will be much much more functionality than just setting color.. so this huge lines of if - else if - else will make it real slow and sluggish..

Comment: my actual number of row counts (i.e. lines of codes is) -- 200+ which is a real pain and also a very bad thing for the eyes to look at :(